# ggplot with text and arrows - cannot save to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I was trying to annotate a figure (density plot) using geom_text to place a label on the figure and geom_segment so that it points an arrow an element.

When the density plot is based on a **reasonable amount of data points** (<= 1e4) everything works as expected (**I can use ggsave to export as pdf**) but when I have **more data points** (>= 1e5) the plot does not save as pdf - **the file is empty** -- though the plot can be successfully be saved as a png.

I tried the pdf device as well since I can display the plot in R - but this does not work either.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

N=1e5
data=data.frame(x=rnorm(N),y=rexp(N))

p1<-ggplot(data,aes(x=x))+geom_density()+geom_text(aes(label="hello",x=0,y=0.2))+
geom_segment(aes(x=0.1, xend=1.25, y=0.2, yend=0.2),arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")))

p2<-ggplot(data,aes(x=y))+geom_density()+geom_text(aes(label="hello",x=0,y=0.2))+
geom_segment(aes(x=0.1, xend=1.25, y=0.2, yend=0.2),arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")))

pdf('test_device.pdf')
grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol=2)
dev.off()

ggsave('test.pdf',arrangeGrob(p1,p2,ncol=2),height=7,width=10)

ggsave('test.png',arrangeGrob(p1,p2,ncol=2),height=7,width=10)
```

Any clue as to why this might happen?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here, everything works fine and the 3 files are created both with `N=1e4` and `N=1e6`

Comment: I also had no problem.  I am running R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10), x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit), and OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite).

Comment: I had the issue in both Linux (arch) and windows (10) with R 2.2.1 and 2.2.4.

Comment: Tried on a third computer - the pdf can be opened but it takes a lot of time - I guess it's an issue with the pdf viewer and the pdf being too complex. Thanks!